# stash/unstash to transfer data from a build container to other node ( in jenkins)

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops

in my CI infrastrucure i have a jenkins master running as a container and 2 slaves (vms) .
i try to run a build inside a docker container on a node so during the build process i was stashed my target folder to use it later on other node .
in the job's log i can see that the folder stashed succefully.
when the build was finished the container is automatically destroyed then in the next step i unstash that folder to acheive another stages in separate node but nothings happened.. seems like unstash didn't anything.

plz how can i transfer my target from the container to another node or even to the master???

this my pipeline code :

```html
node('docker') {
  stage('Checkout Code') {
      checkout scm
          }
  stage('Build') {
    withMaven( jdk: 'jdk_8', maven: 'maven 3') {
        mvn 'clean install'
        stash name: 'war', includes: 'x.war'
    }
  }

node('master') {
  stage('test') {
    withMaven( jdk: 'jdk_8', maven: 'maven 3') {
      unstash : 'war'
      sh 'mvn clean test'
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that the war is actually being stashed since the generated war should not be in the same directory where you executed `mvn clean install`.

I expect the war to be under target. You may want to change `includes: 'x.war'` to `includes: 'target/x.war'`. Alternatively, go to the maven repository where the war is installed and stash the file from there:

```
withMaven( jdk: 'jdk_8', maven: 'maven 3') {
  mvn 'clean install'
  dir('<path to war>'){
      stash name: 'war', includes: 'x.war'
  }
}
```

Comment: It means it works to `stash` / `unstash` between a docker agent and the jenkins master... Whoaaa, that is more surprising than the question.